# Yii2 : How to write distinct SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to implement following SQL queries in Yii 2 but with no success.

This should give total number of unique company names:

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT(company_name)) FROM clients
```

And this should display `company_name` with `client code` and `id(PK)`:

```sql
SELECT (DISTINCT(company_name,client_code)) FROM clients
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You want to return a table that has two columns: company_name and client_code; unique values only? The union will create a single column of both names and ID's combined. I suspect that's not what you want. Couldn't you just: `select distinct company_name, client_code from clients`?

Comment: First I want the count of all Unique **comapny_name** and after that in second query I want to list  of all unique **company_name** and **client_code**

Comment: Does the first query work (i.e. `count(distinct(company_name))`)? The syntax looks good to me.

Comment: got the count of unique company name but dont know how to list those..

Comment: Can you try `select distinct company_name, client_code from clients`?

Comment: i want syntax in yii2 format

Comment: did you try: `$data = (new yii\db\Query())->select(['company_name', 'client_code'])->from('clients')->distinct()->all();` ?

Comment: Please post your findings as a new answer.  Providing (and selecting) an answer to your own question makes it easier for people with the same problem to find a solution.

Comment: @tarleb did it.. :)
thanks for pointing this..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Answering my own question I got following working solutions:

**Got the count for unique `company_name`:**

```
$my = (new yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['company_name',])
    ->from('create_client')
    ->distinct()
    ->count();
echo $my;
```

**List of distinct `company_name` and `client_code`:**

```
$query = new yii\db\Query();
$data = $query->select(['company_name','client_code'])
    ->from('create_client')
    ->distinct()
    ->all();
if ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo 'company_name: ' . $row['company_name'] . ' client_code: ' . $row['client_code'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
$total = YourModel::find()->select('company_name')->distinct()->count();
```

In Search Model:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = YourModel::find()->select('company_name')->distinct();
    // or
    $query = YourModel::find()->select(['company_name', 'client_code'])->distinct();

    $query->orderBy('id desc');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this sample is useful for you

```
 $names = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT  count(DISTINCT(company_name)) as name FROM clients')
    ->queryAll();
```

for access the the data

```
foreach ($names as $name){
    echo $name['name'];
}
```

Comment: I have post a new answer. i hope this is correct for you.

Comment: Change the way to access the db object, It is `db` instead of `$db`, related https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-dao#creating-db-connections (Creating DB Connections)

Answer (score 2):

All worked fine

```
return Clients::find()->count('DISTINCT(company_name)');
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who need select distinct on and other columns with aliases, the following solution will work:

```
$modelClass::find()
    ->select(new Expression(
        "distinct on ('col1') col1, col2, test as col3, 'hardCodeValue' as col4"
    ))
```

Note: for PGSQL it is important what quotes you put in the query.