# Getting Distinct rows from a Db in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

[i tried this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361571/yii2-how-to-write-distinct-sql-query) but with no luck. My requirement is that i have a table called 'tabAccount'. it has some duplicate values and null values for the field
'parent_account'. I want to select only the distinct values for the field parent_account, also field group_or_ledger with value Ledger and field root_type with value Expense . How can i do this?

i tried something like this

```
$expense    =   TabAccount::find()->select('DISTINCT `parent_account`')->where(['root_type'=>'Expense'])
                    ->andWhere(['group_or_ledger'=>'Ledger'])
                    ->andWhere(['not', ['parent_account' => null]])->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

distinct is a boolean function see [Yii2 api distinct()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#distinct%28%29-detail)

```
$query = TabAccount::find();
$query->select('parent_account');
$query->distinct();
$query->where(['root_type'=>'Expense']);
$query->andWhere(['group_or_ledger'=>'Ledger'])
$query->andWhere(['not', ['parent_account' => null]]);
$expense = $query->all();
```

You can also try:

```
$query = new Query;             
$query->select('parent_account')
->from(TabAccount::tableName())
->distinct()
->where(['root_type'=>'Expense'])
->andWhere(['group_or_ledger'=>'Ledger'])
->andWhere(['not', ['parent_account' => null]]);

$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: it gave me zero result

Comment: what is the executed query sql?

Comment: my bad i was executing it on the wrong action. i tried the first one and it worked.