# How to avoid redundancy when show data in Yii2 Gridview?

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I've successfully sorting showed data in Yii2 gridview based on Id. Using `$dataProvider` in controller:

```
$dataProvider->setSort([
        'defaultOrder' => ['id' => SORT_DESC]
]);
```

But it also show data redundant, like this

```
 __________________________
| Id |   Name   |   City   |
| 1  |  Angela  |  Alabama |
| 2  |  Brenda  |  Boston  |
| 3  |  Angela  |  Alabama |
```

**how to set `$dataProvider` so it avoid redundancy?**
So the data in gridview will show like this:

```
 __________________________
| Id |   Name   |   City   |
| 1  |  Angela  |  Alabama |
| 2  |  Brenda  |  Boston  |
```

Thanks

Comment: You can filter data using `where` condition in your `$dataProvider` query

Comment: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361571/yii2-how-to-write-distinct-sql-query)